# How to add 30 min to current system time and start countdown on button click

Tags: timer, runnable, countdown

I have tried a lot but my textview is not changing.

Timer should automatically add 30 min to current time and it will be my future time event  on button. Click

```
static final long ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS=60000;//millisecs

Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
long t= date.getTimeInMillis();
Date afterAdding30Mins=new Date(t + (30 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));

private void countDownStart() {
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                if (!current_date.after(afterAdding30Mins)) {
                    long diff = t+ 1800000;
                    long minutes = (diff / 1000) / 60;
                    long seconds = (diff / 1000) % 60;

                    String timeLeftFormattedm = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", minutes);
                    String timeLeftFormatteds = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d", seconds);
                    //

                    tv_minute.setText(timeLeftFormattedm);
                    tv_second.setText(timeLeftFormatteds);
                } else {
                    linear_layout_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    linear_layout_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
}
```

Comment: In simple words, when a button is clicked, you want to start a CountDown? You don't need the calendar class, you can do this with the CountDownTimer class. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: Yes I know that but in countdown timer class I am unable to save state of timer so I am approaching this method, I mean when I close the app timer stops , please suggest me how can. I do it

Comment: Oh! I understand now.. Why not use a BroadcastReceiver then? Even when the app is closed, everything still works fine!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but I am completely noob so don't know much about service and reciever , if you have time kindly tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **BroadcastReceiver**. With a BroadcastReceiver, you can schedule tasks or events for the future and they'd still run/work even when the app is destroyed/shutdown. In your case, you can call the BroadcastReceiver immediately after your button click and schedule for 30 minutes.

To understand how BroadcastReceivers work: Read through [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) or take a look at  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296987/what-is-broadcastreceiver-and-when-we-use-it).

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD0rybdMtGk)  would also give you a headstart,

Comment: Can you please see this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448539/how-to-save-state-of-countdown-timer-even-if-the-app-is-destroyed?noredirect=1#comment83907024_48448539

Comment: Can you give me some video tutorial for broadcast with  countdown timer? I am unable to do anything with broadcast reciever